# Geographic grid search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, geocoding, geospatial, geography

Many of the location based services provide APIs for finding places/venues/spots around a given latitude longitude pair.  I'm looking into how I can search for these places across an entire city.

I can build a grid for a city by getting its bounds from the Google Maps Geocoder and then incrementing the lat/longs to lay down points to form the grid.  I've [prototyped this grid](http://placesignal.appspot.com/grid)  (click the Fill Grid button to see all of the points) to visualize this idea.

```
// gather a collection of lat/long pairs that represents a grid of the city
    var latIncrement = .04;
    var lngIncrement = .04;
    var newLat = nw.lat();
    while(newLat >= sw.lat()) {
      var newLng = nw.lng();
      while(newLng <= ne.lng()) {
        // western and northern border as well as grid infill
        addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
        newLng += lngIncrement;
      }

      // eastern border
      addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, ne.lng()));
      newLat -= latIncrement;
    }

    // southern border
    var newLng = sw.lng();
    while(newLng <= se.lng()) {
      addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), newLng));
      newLng += lngIncrement;
    }
    addMarker(se);
```

I can then take all of these points and run searches for them against the LBS APIs.

My question is, are there more scientific ways/algorithms to establish this grid?  I'd like to learn more about them.  I'm just arbitrarily incrementing the lat/lngs until I reach the border of the grid.  The density of places is going to vary wildly by city and area of a city, so sometimes the increment will be too small, and sometimes too large.  I'm looking for ideas about how to tune this a little better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perhaps more efficient/clean way would be to find the [bounding rectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of the city, which is the rectangle with each edge being the extreme cardinal points between the city border points, if you can find them, and then filling them in iteratively.  But that is basically what you are already doing, anyway.

As for place density, do you have a specific API that you are going to be using this with?  If you know the "reach" of the your API's points when detecting places, you ever only have to have grid points as close as their radius.

That being said, have you looked into seeing perhaps if the API directly supports searching for places **within a border**?  That might be your best and cleanest bet.

---

After reading your comment, here is a possibly inefficient way that I'm going to think over and refine in the future, but it might help you get started.

Place a point in the center of your city, and observe all locations detected.  Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your locations, and place a new point on each location on the convex hull.  Then, add to your list of locations all locations that fall within reach of these newly added points.

Then, find the convex hull of those, and repeat the same process.

This might actually reduce your amount of points for sparsely populated cities.  For dense ones, it might be less than optimal, but it might get you started on a working track.

Comment: I've been looking at foursquare, twitter, gowalla, and yelp APIs. Radius (reach) is a common parameter, but the problem becomes the number of results returned (they limit it to a handful per search), so I can't get all of the places in the city with a single search.  Good ideas, I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Great, this gives me another way to tackle it.  I like how since it's spreading out from the center, it's not as wasteful. With the grid search, many of the searches would be outside the city limits. Thanks for spinning on this.

Answer (score 0):

While I was facing same problem. I came up with a solution, where you will go do grid search in a top down recursive way. This will work if that API supports bounding box search. Initially assume your city as a square. Now fetch data/places using API in that square (bounding box query). Now if number of returned places are more than some threshold, than split the city square into 4 equal squares and repeat the process for each square. Don't split if number of returned places are less. This will prevent grid searching into non business areas (squares) like forests,rivers etc. Here is the prototype python code for that:

Here fetch is function which fetch results from API based on bounding box with sw as southwest latitude,logitude tuple and ne as northeast latitude,logitude tuple

```
allresults = []

def grid_search(sw,ne):
    global results
    results = fetch(sw,ne)
    if len(results) <= 10:
        return
    allresults.append(results)
    swlat,swlon = sw
    nelat,nelon = ne
    grid_search( (swlat + delta, swlon), (nelat, sw + delta) )
    grid_search( (swlat + delta, swlon + delta), ne )
    grid_search( sw, (swlat + delta, swlon + delta) )
    grid_search( (swlat,swlon + delta), (swlat + delta, nelon) )
```